How to run periodic task in Django without using celery?
I need run a periodic task in Django to update some Prometheus metrics, then I realized that I cannot use celery, because celery runs in other workers while Prometheus metrics are in-memory objects.
I am quite new to Django. If I do this in Go, I will start a thread (go-routine), but I am not sure if I should start a thread in Django as Django is like a block-box to me. If I should, then where to start to thread? In settings.py or elsewhere?

How are you serving the app? ASGI or WSGI?

@Selcuk Yes, WSGI.

In that case you can start a background thread (example).

the easy way in your situation would be writing a function to handle metrics for Prometheus and use system cron to handle periodicity…

Thanks for your answer. What do you mean "system cron"? I want the function to run within the same process as Django.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Please check this:
https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/3.x/
I used APScheduler on my previous company projects and it works just fine.

You can create a new process in python with an scheduler and do your task there and run this as daemon in background.
https://schedule.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html
You can execute a single task periodically with cron.
You can use other libraries like huey https://huey.readthedocs.io/en/latest/django.html
